# Weinberg’s proof of Wigner's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, symmetry

I'm working through the proof of Wigner's theorem in Weinberg's The Quantum Theory of Fields Volume 1 Chapter 2 Appendix A pp. 91. Consider the following steps of the proof

Let $\left\{\psi_{k} \epsilon \mathbb{R}_{k}\right\}_{k=1}^{n}$ be a complete orthonormal basis. Then,
$$
\left|\left\langle\psi_{k} \mid \psi_{l}\right\rangle\right|=\delta_{k l}
$$
Let $\psi_{k}^{\prime}$ be some arbitrary choice of vector belonging to the transformed ray $\mathbb{R}_{k} .$ Then, we have
$$
\left|\left\langle\psi_{k}^{\prime} \mid \psi_{l}^{\prime}\right\rangle\right|^{2}=\left|\left\langle\psi_{k} \mid \psi_{l}\right\rangle\right|^{2}=\delta_{k l}\tag{1}
$$
But $\left|\left\langle\psi_{k}^{\prime} \mid \psi_{k}^{\prime}\right\rangle\right|$ is real and positive. Hence $\left|\left\langle\psi_{k}^{\prime} \mid \psi_{k}^{\prime}\right\rangle\right|=1$
Therefore,
$$
\langle\psi_{k}^{\prime} \mid \psi_{l}^{\prime}\rangle=\delta_{k l}\tag{2}
$$

Can anyone explain how to get (2) from (1)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what's unclear to you here? He's just taking the square root.

Comment: how does the condinition of norm always been positive definite get into the derivation of (2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\langle \psi_k|\psi_\ell\rangle |^2$ is a real positive number, let us call it $c^2$. Then $|\langle \psi_k|\psi_\ell\rangle |=\pm c$. But also $|\langle \psi_k|\psi_\ell\rangle |$ is a real positive number, so we need to take the positive square root, here $\delta_{k\ell}$.

Comment: in the proof it is mentioned that $|\langle \psi_k|\psi_k\rangle |$ is a real positive,  Is it same as $|\langle \psi_k|\psi_\ell\rangle |$ being real positive? how?

Comment: Yes, if $k=\ell$ then it is the above, otherwise it is zero.